# How to start with replacing a hardware with FPGA/microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, hardware, alternatives

I'm currently stuck with how to start with a project I took on. The project is that I emulate the results given by a program when connected to a hardware using the same program and a FPGA/microcontroller. Essentially I want to replace the hardware with a programmed FPGA/microcontroller. So, how should I go about this? Thank you.
oh, and sorry, this isn't a white box design.. I know nothing about the schematics of the hardware.. just what the data sheet tells me. and unfortunately I cannot disclose too many details.

Comment: You need a complete description of what the hardware does, to start with.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to start by learning how to program FPGAs.

Answer (score 5):

If this is a "white box" design, i.e. you already know the hardware design (schematics / netlist, or Boolean design equations) then you can begin by translating the hardware design directly into Verilog or VHDL hardware description language. (Both of these HDL languages are open-source standards, and for most purposes either one will be fine.)

If the hardware is a "black box" design, i.e. you only know its external behavior and do not know how it is implemented, it's more difficult because you must effectively create an equivalent hardware design in Verilog or VHDL.

At this stage you will also build an HDL test fixture, to simulate the applied interactions between the existing software and the new replacement hardware. In addition, you will need to validate the test fixture to ensure that it does essentially the same things the existing driver program does, in the same way, and also check that the test fixture can correctly detect test failure results.

Either way, the next step is to run simulation of the HDL code to validate the design description can work under ideal conditions. If the simulation fails, there's definitely a problem with the design, but if the simulation doesn't fail, there could still be problems. Real hardware has propagation delays that are dependent on internal routing, and if your design has race conditions, you may find that the design works in simulation but not on the real FPGA.

Finally, after validating the test fixture and checking the simulation results, you begin synthesis, and wade through all the generated reports. I strongly recommend checking RTL schematic (register-transfer logic) to make sure that the synthesis tools actually synthesized all of the requested HDL code. **Not all HDL code can be synthesized into FPGA hardware,** and these can be "silent failures" that don't show up clearly unless you carefully read all the reports generated by the synthesis tools.

If the system is very sensitive to timing, you should also go back and run **Post-Synthesis Simulation**, which takes into account the exact physical location on-chip of each flip-flop and each route's propagation delays, to produce a more accurate simulation of the real FPGA's timing. If the design is robust, this should give the same simulation results as the ideal simulation.

Use a COTS (Commercial, Off-The-Shelf) FPGA board for initial development, this will save a great deal of time and effort over trying to get your very first FPGA board to work -- there's enough things that can go wrong with developing the FPGA configuration (bitstream), you shouldn't also have to worry about whether your power supply LDO regulators can deliver enough current or whether the bypassing is sufficient, or if the FPGA BGA package is reliably soldered to the board. I've been through that myself...  If you were a really high-volume customer, you would already be talking with Xilinx or Altera technical sales anyway, maybe get them to design your board... But for us little guys, COTS is the only practical way to go.